# Python hangs if there are more than one lines in the entry file

Tags: python, web-scraping

Python hangs whenever i try to run this with more than one line in the `StocksList.txt`

Stockslist test values can be accessed [here](https://pastebin.com/sPdHPzZM).

```
import requests
import time
import chime

infile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/Final/Marketsmithindia/StocksList.txt'
outfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/Final/Marketsmithindia/InstrumentID.csv'
failfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/Final/Marketsmithindia/Failout.txt'

timeout = 10
search_url = (
    "https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/srch.json"
)
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

# Calculating time
start = time.time()

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT, open(failfile, 'w') as FAIL:
   for DATA in IN:
       try:
           STOCK = DATA.strip()  # Remove newline and split the data
           params = {"text": STOCK} # <-- your symbol here
           data = requests.get(search_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
           InstrumentID = data["response"]["results"][0]["instrumentId"]
           try:
               line = '%s,%s' % (
                   STOCK,
                   InstrumentID
                   
               )
               print(line, file=OUT)
           except KeyError as E:
               print(DATA, 'KeyError:', E)
       except Exception:
           print(DATA, file=FAIL)       
end = time.time()
file1 = open(failfile,"a")
runtime = round((end-start),3)
print('Total runtime is: ' + str(runtime) + ' Seconds',file = file1)
file1.close()
chime.theme('material')
chime.success()
```

Comment: Side note: using `lowercase` names for constants and `UPPERCASE` names for modified variables is contrary to Python conventions, and may confuse people reading your code

Comment: `Python hangs` — what's the exception text/code?

Comment: Does it work correctly for all the stocks in your list if you run with one line at a time in the file?

Comment: The HTTP GET request hangs when the stock is VIKASWSP. This is an issue with the endpoint you're calling. You should probably implement a timeout to handle such problems

Comment: @slothrop yes it is working

Comment: @erukumk so VIKASWSP works if it is the only line in your file? Sounds like the API may be rate-limiting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your endpoint behaves poorly when it doesn't understand/recognise the parameters passed to it. You should probably implement a timeout to cope with this.

For example:

```
import requests

URL = "https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/srch.json"
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

with open("StocksList.txt") as stocks:
    for stock in map(str.strip, stocks):
        params = {"text": stock}
        try:
            with requests.get(
                URL, headers=HEADERS, params=params, timeout=5
            ) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            print(f"Request timed out for {stock}")
```